# How to display values from an array of objects within a given range with RamdaJS

Tags: javascript, filtering, ramda.js

I am trying to create a function to filter an array of objects. I need to display all numbers between 2 numbers that I put in my search. I would like to use Ramda. Does anyone have any suggestions?

For example: I have following array of objects:

```
[{num: 120},{num: 110},{num: 115},{num: 5},{num: 35}]
```

I would like to display all numbers between 99 and 119. How can I do that with RamdaJS?

Comment: Please see [ask]. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

[.filter](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter) is the function for this. For example:

```
const inputArray = [{num: 120},{num: 110},{num: 115},{num: 5},{num: 35}];
const min = 99;
const max = 119;
const outputArray = R.filter(val => val >= min && val <= max, inputArray);
```

If you're trying to have a factory for creating filter functions with different min and max values, that would look something like:

```
function makeFilter(min, max) {
  return R.filter(val => val >= min && val <= max);
}

// used like:
const filter = makeFilter(99, 119);
const outputArray = filter(inputArray);
```